# Union type acting in unexpected way

Tags: typescript

```
interface A {
  a: number;
}

interface B extends A {
  b: number;
}

let ab: A | B = {
  a: 1
};

ab.b = 2;
```

I thought it's a valid code - `ab` at first acts as `A` and then after adding the field I was expecting it to act as a `B`. Unfortunately it does not:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:307
        throw new TSError(formatDiagnostics(diagnosticList, cwd, ts, lineOffset))
              ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
test.ts (13,4): Property 'b' does not exist on type 'A'. (2339)
    at getOutput (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:307:15)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:336:16
    at Object.compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:496:11)
    at Module.m._compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:392:43)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:395:12)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
```

It seems like it has wrong type. It thinks the `ab` is of type `A`, but it is clearly defined as of type `A | B`...

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this another instance of TypeScript's not-that-great type system?

Edit: To clarify things, I **want** "either" type which I think is the union type. I was expecting that `ab` is of type `A | B`. After initialization acts as of type `A` (because it has only fields of `A`) and after modification I was expecting to start acting as type `B` (since it has all the fields of `B`).

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**:

You've clarified that you don't want an intersection type (see "Original Answer" below).

Because you've put `{a: 1}` into `ab`, the compiler knows that `ab` definitely contains an `A`, which has no `b` property. Apparently it doesn't allow for the possibility that you'd *convert* the object from `A` to `B` by adding `b` to it.

You can instead create a new `B` object:

```
ab = {a: ab.a, b: 2};
```

[The playground says](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20b%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20ab%3A%20A%20%7C%20B%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%201%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aab%20%3D%20%7Ba%3A%20ab.a%2C%20b%3A%202%7D%3B) the compiler's perfectly happy with that.

---

**Original Answer**:

*Union types* are for either/or situations, such as when a function accepts *either* a string *or* a number for a given parameter. I suspect you're looking for an *intersection type* (`A & B`, both/and), not a union type (`A | B`, either/or) (more: [Advanced Types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)):

```
interface A {
  a: number;
}

interface B extends A {
  b: number;
}

let ab: A & B = {
  a: 1,
  b: 0
};

ab.b = 2;
```

Note that I've added a `b` property to the object initializer, since otherwise `ab` isn't a `B`.

Comment: I wanted "either" - so `ab` can be `A` or `B`. Your way I can straight just use `B`, because it can't be never `A`.

Comment: @monnef: A single object cannot be "either" `A` or `B`. You have to choose. `|` makes sense as a *parameter* type because for any given call, the parameter is one of the types or the other. It doesn't make sense for what you're using it for.

Comment: Why it doesn't make sense to be of type `A | B`? From a logical point of view it IMO does, I have added more info to the question.

Comment: @monnef: `ab` can be `A | B`, but that means it can hold an `A` *or* it can hold a `B`. It can't hold both at the same time. I think your existing code doesn't work because the compiler knows the object you've assigned to `ab` is of type `A`, hence not having a `b` property. With `let ab: A | B;`, you *can* do `ab = {a: 1, b: 2}` (e.g., an entirely new object), but not `let ab = {a: 1}` (`ab` now definitely contains an `A` object) and then `ab.b = 2`. I guess the compiler isn't clevery enough to realize that converts the `A` object into a `B` object.

Comment: @monnef: I've folded that into a revised answer above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder +1

Answer (score 0):

After you has assigned the `{ a: 1 }` object, the `ab` object is treated by typescript as object of a certain type (`A`), with the only property - `a`.

In this case

```
let ab: A | B = {
  a: 1
};
```

you are assigning defenitely object of `A` type, without `b` property.
And transpiler throws error on

```
ab.b = 2;
```

It's similar as if you are already in the corresponding type guard if-brunch:

```
function f(ab: A | B) {
   if(ab instanceof A) {
       // You are here
       // There is no `b` property in this brunch
   }
   esle {
   }
}
```

Comment: "you are assigning defenitely object without b property. And transpiler throws error on"
Not true. `A | B` type can have `b` property, or what for would be the union type if one can't use properties which are not in both types?

Comment: A | B type can have `b` property, but the `{ a: 1 }` object has no such a property,

Comment: But `ab` is of type `A | B` not `{ a: number; }` (which is equivalent to `A`). I am modifying `ab` not untyped object `{ a: 1 }`.

Comment: After you has assigned the `{ a: 1 }` object, the `ab` object is treated by typescript as a certain object type, with the only property - `a`.